# Get the size of a single message in Google Cloud PubSub

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a setup where I am publishing messages to [Google Cloud PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs#docs) service.

**I wish to get the size of each individual message that I am publishing to PubSub**. So for this, I identified the following approaches (Note: I am using the Python clients for publishing and subscribing, following a line-by-line implementation as presented in their documentation):

- View the message count from the Google Cloud Console using the '[Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring)' feature
- Create a [pull subscription client](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull) and view the size using `message.size` in the callback function for the messages that are being pulled from the requested topic.
- Estimate the size of the messages before [publishing](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher) by converting them to JSON as per the [PubSub message schema](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage) and using `sys.getsizeof()`

For a sample message like as follows which I published using a Python publisher client:

```
{
  "data": 'Test_message',
  "attributes": {
    'dummyField1': 'dummyFieldValue1',
    'dummyField2': 'dummyFieldValue2'
  }
}
```

, I get the size as 101 as the `message.size` output from the following callback function in the subcription client:

```
def callback(message):
    print(f"Received {message.data}.")
    if message.attributes:
        print("Attributes:")
        for key in message.attributes:
            value = message.attributes.get(key)
            print(f"{key}: {value}")
    print(message.size)
    message.ack()
```

Whereas the size displayed on Cloud Console Monitoring is something around 79 B.
[image]

So these are my questions:

- **Why are the sizes different for the same message?**
- **Is the output of `message.size` in bytes?**
- **How do I view the size of a message before publishing using the python client?**
- **How do I view the size of a single message on the Cloud Console, rather than a aggregated measure of size during a given timeframe which I could find in the Monitoring section?**

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/subscriber/api/message.html?highlight=size), the **message.size** is an attribute that `Return the size of the underlying message, in bytes`. Regarding your question about the value of **message_sizes** this metric means the `Distribution of publish message sizes (in bytes). It is Sampled every 60 seconds. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 240 seconds`, [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub). Could you tell me the reason you want to check the message size before publishinhg?

Comment: Also, would `message.size` and 'message_sizes` (as mentioned above) satisfy your needs?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes I wish to know the size of messages that are being published to have an estimate of the dataflow if messages are being published at a specified rate for a specified number of days. This is in turn to estimate how much it would cost, and whether it would stay within the free tier.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes `message.size` being in bytes, confirms one of my queries. But I am not sure how to use the 'message_sizes' property.

Comment: Also, I don't think I can use `message.size` in the publisher. `message` is an entity in the subscription client.

Comment: If you want to monitor the quota you are reaching, you can use Cloud Monitoring and set up alerts based on specific metrics such as `pubsub.googleapis.com/topic/byte_cost`. Here are some links for you to understand better how it works: [Quota utilization](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring#utilization), [Alert event based](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-pubsub-drainer), [Alert Policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui). Would it satisfy your needs?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Thanks, I had come across this monitoring metric. But as mentioned in the question, what I specifically wanted to understand is whether the python client has this functionality.

Comment: According to the Python Library documentation you only have the message.size as a message attribute for the subscriber. Otherwise, you will have to use Cloud Monitoring and alerts, which is very useful if you want to monitor your quota expenditure. Did all this information help you?

Comment: In order to further contribute to the community, I will gather the info we discussed in the comments and post as an answer. Is it ok for you?

Comment: Yes, please. That would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to further contribute to the community, I am summarising our discussion as an answer.

1. Regarding `message.size`, it is an attribute from a message in the subscriber client. In addition, according to the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/subscriber/api/message.html?highlight=message%20size), its definition is:

> Returns the size of the underlying message, in bytes

Thus you would not be able to use it before publishing.

2. On the opposite side, `message_size` is a metric in Google Cloud Metrics and it is used by Cloud Monitoring, [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub).

Finally, the last topic discussed was that your aim is to monitor your quota expenditure, so you can stay in the free tier. For this reason, the best option would be using Cloud Monitoring and setup alerts based on the metrics such as `pubsub.googleapis.com/topic/byte_cost`. Here are some links, where you can find more about it:  [Quota utilisation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring#utilization), [Alert event based](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring#utilization), [Alert Policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your third question about viewing the message size before publishing, the billable message size is the sum of the message data, the attributes (key plus value), 20 bytes for the timestamp, and some bytes for the `message_id`. See the [Cloud Pub/Sub Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/pricing) guide. Note that the minimum of 1000 bytes is billable regardless of message size so if your messages may be smaller than 1000 bytes it’s important to have good [batch settings](https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/publisher/index.html#batching). The `message_id` is assigned server-side and is not guaranteed to be a certain size but it is returned by the [publish call as a future](https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/publisher/index.html#futures) so you can see examples. This should allow you to get a pretty accurate estimate of message cost within the publisher client. Note that you can also use the [monitoring client library](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries) to read Cloud Monitoring metrics from within the Python client.

Regarding your fourth question, there’s no way to extract single data points from a distribution metric (Unless you have only published one message during the time period in the query in which case the mean would tell you the size of that one message).